# Django test model with fake user

Tags: django, django-tests

I have a django model I want to test. The model includes a 'user' field. Is there a way of creating a temporary user for the purposes of testing?

tests.py

```
from django.test import TestCase
from .models import Task
from django.utils import timezone
from .forms import Taskform

# models test
class TaskTest(TestCase):

    def create_task(self, title="Title", description="A description"):
        return Task.objects.create(title=title, pub_date=timezone.datetime.now(), completed=False, description=description, user='user')

    def test_task_creation(self):
        w = self.create_task()
        self.assertTrue(isinstance(t, Task))
        self.assertEqual(t.__unicode__(), t.title)
```

Comment: ... yes of course there is, in exactly the same way you create a Task. What is your question?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well a `User` is actually *just* another Django model (of course it has some extra bindings in Django which makes it a "popular" and "special" model, but it has the same interface, and you can construct instances like with other models). So you can import that model, and create a `User`.

For example:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

my_user = User.objects.create(username='Testuser')
```

Typically in tests, one however uses a *factory* (for example with the [Factory Boy](http://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/recipes.html)) to make it easy to construct objects with some data. For example:

```
import factory
from factory.django import DjangoModelFactory

class UserFactory(DjangoModelFactory):

    username = factory.Sequence('testuser{}'.format)
    email = factory.Sequence('testuser{}@company.com'.format)

    class Meta:
        model = User
```

You can then create a user with:

```
my_user2 = UserFactory()
my_user3 = UserFactory(username='alice')
my_user4 = UserFactory(username='bob', email='bob@work.com')
```

Comment: I don't get how to apply the test to a factory_boy user? This doesn't work user = UserFactory() \n self.assertEqual(t.user, user)

Comment: @Davtho1983: well if you construct such factory, you can *call* the factory to create a user (see edit). The advantage is that the factory will here pick sequence values, if you do not fill in anything. So as a result even if you do not provide  a `username`, it will fill in one, for example `username='testuser412'`.

Comment: @Davtho1983: how did you create the `t`? Did you perhaps have *reassigned* `user` to a *new* user?

Comment: I'm not getting how you reference the Userfactory object in the test - I create with user = UserFactory(username='bob')
        return Task.objects.create(title=title, pub_date=timezone.datetime.now(), completed=False, description=description, user=user)self.assertEqual(t.user, 'bob') ??

Comment: No, the test should be `self.assertEqual(t.user, user)`, or `self.assertEqual(t.user.username, 'bob')`, although the latter is of course easier to satisfy.

Comment: I call t = self.create_task() which is a funciton that creates the test user